# Can I use PHP inside Salesforce? (not access SF API, but actually run PHP inside SF)

Tags: php, salesforce

First post on SO so be gentle :)

My company is wanting to implement Salesforce.com and I am attempting to place one of my already-built sites (PHP and HTML5) into the platform with the SF GUI removed. That part is done. However, I have noticed that any PHP includes or requires, or any PHP for that matter is NOT being executed.

So my question is basically to confirm whether or not this is possible, and if it is, is there something I'm not doing right?

(pleeeeeease don't make me learn Apex lol)

Comment: I don't think PHP can be used inside of Salesforce. Apex is the default. You can, however, link from Salesforce to your PHP apps and vice versa. Don't avoid Apex; you will do quite well with Apex.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to have a look at Salesforce Canvas, you can surface any app in any language within salesforce using a javascript sdk.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Canvas

Answer (score 0):

NO, It is not possible.

Salesforce executes Apex/Visualforce Only.